# Should not allow comma at the begining and end

Tags: regex

I am trying to write a regex pattern to allow everything but it should not allow comma at the beginning or at the end. Can anyone help me with this.

Comment: show your "try"

Comment: This is not something you need regex for, just two simple checks, one for beginning, one for end.

Comment: this is a tool which accepts regex only and not any kind of java or .net coding where I can check it. So only regex is needed.

Answer (score 1):

Try this regex.It should work

```
^[^,].+[^,]$
```